# Check if a delegate is a method of an object, and retrieve this object reference, and method name

Tags: c#, methods, reference, delegates

I want to know if this is possible given a delegate variable, to know if it is actually pointing to an object method, and to retrieve this object and the method's name.

e.g:

```
public delegate void test();
public static test testDel = null;
public void TestMethod()
{
    ;
}
public void TestDelegate()
{
    //here it is not a method of an object
    testDel += () => { };
    // here it is "TestMethod"
    testDel += this.TestMethod;
    // i want something like that:
    SomeDelegateInfoClass[] infos = testDel.GetAssignedObjectsAndMethodNames();
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes it's possible, delegate contains couple of properties just for that. First one is `Target` (target object) and second is `Method` (of type `MethodInfo`).

```
var target = testDel.Target; // null for static methods
var methodName = testDel.Method.Name;
```

Note however that in this case

```
testDel = () => { };
```

it's not true that this is "not a method of an object". Compiler will create new type and your empty anonymous function will be a method of that type. So

```
testDel = () => { };
var targetType = testDel.Target.GetType().Name; // will be something like <>c - name of compiler-generated type
var m = testDel.Method.Name; // will be something like <Main>b__2_0 - compiler generated name
```

Note also that if you add multiple methods to delegate, like this:

```
testDel += () => { };    
testDel += this.TestMethod;
```

`Target` and `Method` will contain information about **last** added method. To get information about all of them, you need to use `GetInvocationList`:

```
if (testDel != null) {
    foreach (var del in testDel.GetInvocationList()) {
       Console.WriteLine(del.Target);
       Console.WriteLine(del.Method);
    }
}
```